# Prisma nested recursive relations depth

Tags: sql, database, recursion, relation, prisma

I must query a group and **all of its subgroups** from the same model.

However, when fetching from *Group* table as shown below, Prisma doesn't include more than a 1-depth to the resulting *Subgroups* relation (subgroups of subgroups being left out). Subgroups attribute holds an array whose elements are of same type as the said model (recursive).

```
model Group {
  id                Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  parentId          Int?
  Parent            Group?      @relation("parentId", fields: [parentId], references: [id])
  Subgroups         Group[]     @relation("parentId")
}
```

```
GroupModel.findFirst({
  where:   { id: _id },
  include: { Subgroups: true }
});
```

I guess this might be some sort of safeguard to avoid infinite recursive models when generating results. Is there any way of dodging this limitation (if it's one), and if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't supported at the moment. The only possible workaround would be to implement it in SQL using rawQuery. There's [an issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3725) about it in the Prisma repo. I would suggest commenting your use-case over there so we can track the demand for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can query more than 1-depth nested subgroups by nesting `include` like so:

```
GroupModel.findFirst({
  where:   { id: _id },
  include: { Subgroups: { include: { Subgroups: { include: Subgroups: { // and so on...  } } } } }
});
```

But, as mentioned by @TasinIshmam, something like `includeRecursive` is not supported by Prisma at the moment.

The workaround would be to use `$queryRaw` (https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#queryraw) together with SQL recursive queries (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE)